# Wrap every 4th product within a div

Tags: html, bigcartel

I need a bit of help. I'm building my own custom BigCartel theme and I run into the following issue: currently I'm listing all my products on the main product page (they aren't that many) and I'm trying to wrap every 4th product within a div. 
Basically I've got

```
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product"></div>
```

and the final result that I want is

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how am I supposed to do this using their templating language.

Comment: so, what's your issue?

Comment: @racecarjonathan I'm not sure how am I supposed to do this using their [templating language](https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/)

Comment: you might want to include that in your post next time...that's a big piece of information you left out...i just edited your post to include it for you

Comment: @racecarjonathan thanks mate, it makes sense. Sorry about that!

Comment: Why do you want to wrap the elements in extra containers? Is this for styling purposes only? My reason for asking is that you can style elements based on count with just CSS (using :nth selectors) without adding more markup.

Comment: @Jayx - thanks for your question. It's not for styling purposes, there's a bit of JS involved there. I tried using nth selectors, but it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [template language](https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/), I think it could be done like this:

```
 <div class="wrap">

 {% for product in products.all %}
   <div class="product ">
     {{ product.name }} </div>
   {% if forloop.index % 4 == 0 %}
     </div>

     <div class="wrap">

   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using jQuery :**

```
var wraps = $('.wrap');
$('.products').each( function(e, i){
  wraps[Math.floor(i/4)].appendChild(e);
})
```

jQuery will return a list (**[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)**) for all products , iterating this list , you can wrap your item in div refering to the list index.

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @mohmad-taher Thanks for your reply. However if I try using your method I get the following error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined'

Comment: `var wraps = $('wrap');` should be `var wraps = $('.wrap');`

Comment: @Seb sorry typo mistake , will be fixed

Answer (score 2):

I tried to be a little clever. Assuming you have several of these `.wrap` elements.

```
var products = document.querySelectorAll('.products'), 
    wraps = document.querySelectorAll('wrap');
[].forEach.call(products, function(e, i){
  wraps[Math.floor(i/4)].appendChild(e);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a little old but I found the accepted answer doesn't work.

This is how I got it to work in the templating language (which is kinda? [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/)):

```
{% for product in products %}

  {% assign zeroindexmodfour = forloop.index0 | modulo: 4  %}
  {% assign indexmodfour = forloop.index | modulo: 4  %}

  {% if zeroindexmodfour == 0 %}
    <div class="wrap">
  {% endif %}

  <div class="product"></div>

  {% if indexmodfour == 0 or forloop.last %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```